# In ledger-cli can I stop automated translation later in the file?

Tags: ledger-cli

If you have an automated transaction in your ledger file, can you later in the file remove it or redefine it?

For example if students live together and

```
= /^expenses:internet/
    mark   .5
    sophie  .5
    assets:shared  -1
```

but later on day X you are 3 or 4 students, you have to change the rules.  My experiments did not succeed. A new rule just adds another bookings, but does not remove the old rule.

How can I remove the old one?

When I just add an inverted rule like

```
= /^expenses:internet/
    mark   -.5
    sophie  -.5
    assets:shared  1
```

the calculations are correct, but a `ledger reg` looks very ugly.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

You can limit based on the date:

```
= /^expenses:internet/ and expr date < [2022-05-03]
    mark   .5
    sophie  .5
    assets:shared  -1
```

Comment: Thanks, thats really great!